Chrome extension built using react, chrome.runtime.sendMessage's response is undefined and Receiving end does not exist
Whenever i load the extension for the first time(I'm doing it in dev mode), or reload the extension, the I get response as undefined(Error retrieving HTML content: undefined) in background.js.
And Error as, Unchecked runtime.lastError: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.
My folder structure is
scraper
dist/
public/
images/
index.html
manifest.json
src/
extensions/
background.js
contentScript.js
App.tsx
utils/
chrome-api.js
App.tsx
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { useRecoilState } from 'recoil';
import messagesState from './states/messages';
import { isValidChromeRuntime } from './utils/chrome-api';
function App() {
  const [htmlContent, setHtmlContent] = useRecoilState(messagesState);

  const scrapeTab = () => {
    if (chrome && chrome.runtime) {
      chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ action: 'getHTML' }, function (response) {
        console.log(response);
        if (response) {
          setHtmlContent(response);
        } else {
          console.error('Error retrieving HTML content:', response);
        }
      });
    } else {
      console.error(
        'Chrome API is not available. Make sure this component is running in a Chrome extension context.',
        chrome
      );
    }
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    if (isValidChromeRuntime()) {
      scrapeTab();
    } else {
      console.log('here');
    }
  }, []);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Slack scraper</h1>
      {JSON.stringify(htmlContent)}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;


background.js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
  if (request.action === 'getHTML') {
    chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, function (tabs) {
      if (tabs.length) {
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(
          tabs[0].id,
          { action: 'getHTML' },
          function (response) {
            if (response) {
              sendResponse(response);
            } else {
              console.error('Error retrieving HTML content:', response);
            }
          }
        );
      }
    });
    return true;
  }
});


contentScript.js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
  if (request.action === 'getHTML') {
    const messages = scrapeTheDoc();
    sendResponse(messages);
  }
});
const scrapeTheDoc = () => {
  const container = document.querySelector('.p-workspace__primary_view_body');
  return container.toString();
};
document.addEventListener('scroll', function () {
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ action: 'scrollEvent' });
});

manifest.json
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "scraper",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Scraper",
  "host_permissions": ["<all_urls>"],
  "icons": {
    "16": "images/logo.png",
    "32": "images/logo.png",
    "180": "images/logo.png",
    "192": "images/logo.png",
    "512": "images/logo.png"
  },
  "offline_enabled": true,
  "permissions": ["storage", "activeTab", "contextMenus", "tabs"],
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["contentScript.js"]
    }
  ],
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "index.html"
  }
}

chrome-api.js
export const isValidChromeRuntime = () => {
  return chrome.runtime && !!chrome.runtime.getManifest();
};


webpack.config.js
const HTMLPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    background: './src/extensions/background.js',
    contentScript: './src/extensions/contentScript.js',
    popup: './src/index.tsx',
  },
  mode: 'production',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(ts|tsx)$/,
        use: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js', '.jsx'],
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: '[name].js',
  },
  plugins: [
    new HTMLPlugin({
      template: './public/index.html',
      chunks: ['popup'],
      filename: 'index.html',
    }),
    new CopyWebpackPlugin({
      patterns: [
        {
          from: './public',
          to: '',
          globOptions: {
            ignore: ['**/index.html'],
          },
        },
      ],
    }),
  ],
};




You need to re-inject content_scripts after reloading/installing the extension in Chrome. 2) Using executeScript directly is much simpler (example) so you won't need content_scripts, background, background.js, and messaging.


Previously I followed your example, I didn't get my issue resolved. Since it is in react and solution is bit different, I messed it up. Is there any exact proper solution?
I faced permissions issue, and later After fixing that also it didnt work
